# Tapping offset issue in ios12

Tags: ios, offset, tap, ios12

I am working on a form that is running inside a webview. After one of the native ios popups comes up and closed, for example when keyboard appears in a text area, or when dropdown popups, there is a tap issue. There is an offset in the tapping that is approximately the height of the keyboard/dropdown popup. So when I tap a point on the form, a different component which is 200-300pixels down is pressed. It only occurs in ios12. 
The only workaround I found for that is pinch-out and in. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fix it by a tricky method,You should try:

```
- (void)keybordDidHide {
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.lastContentOffset, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset)) {
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:self.lastContentOffset];
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
}

- (void)keybordWillShow {
    self.lastContentOffset = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This did work for me.

ViewController.h

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastContentOffset;
```

ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {    
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(onKeyboardWillShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)onKeyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification {
    self.lastContentOffset = self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset;
}

- (void)onKeyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.lastContentOffset, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset)) {
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:self.lastContentOffset];
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(self.lastContentOffset, self.webView.scrollView.contentOffset)) {
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentOffset:self.lastContentOffset];
        [self.webView.scrollView setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
    }
 }
```